# (CLOSED) How to work with global variable in AWS Lambda (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, global-variables

I need an approach in AWS lambda to resolve an issue

### What am I doing now:

I am looking to build a quick script to test my understanding on global variables. In my script, I place a variable outside the handler, and I assign it a value for the sake of declaring it. Then I place an addition statement within the handler hoping that for every invocaIion, variable i will be added 1.  n a way, I am expecting this to work like a test counter - every time I test the lambda script, AWS prepares the environment, run the script, record down the changes (+1), shuts off while storing the latest value (1) in global variable i.

```
import json
import boto3

i = 0

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    i+=1        
    print(i)
```

### My problem is

I was expecting the output to be 1,2,3,4,5.... However, what happened was it only output 1 all the time. I suppose this could be due to me declaring variable i as 0 , but such is required as I need to declare i.

### What I need

I need some solution (most likely a global variable) to store and pass down the values generated from each lambda script invocation down to the subsequent one.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a single Lambda execution environment will be reused over and over. It sounds like each time you are testing your function a new instance of your function is being created. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: @MarkB exactly. I am trying to store the data in DynamoDB now.

Comment: New to Lambdas, I can't even get this to work. I want to be able to set a dataset in Event JSON and use it for testing. I can't even set global variables inside lambda_handler for the script to interpret. I guess I don't quite understand how Lambda's are suppose to be designed.